# Laravel 4.2 partial view is not compiling

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to render one blade template file into another, but my partial view file is not compiling. I was following the documentation 
[here](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/templates), there is example :

`@include('view.name', array('some'=>'data'))`

So I wrote this in top view file `add_document.blade`

```
<div id="docs_panel">
   @include('board._document_list', array('boards'=>$boards))
</div>
```

and I got compiled html but not compiled blade tags, stuff like
`@foreach($board->drawings as $doc) @endforeach {{ Form::checkbox('check',1,null,array('id'=>'checkb'))}}`
Really dont know how to fix this, I made like in documentation.. Any ideas?

Comment: can you make the question a bit clear? did you get any error? if yes, then what is the error? if html is compiling, then what is not working?

Comment: Yeah html is compiling, but blade tags - no. So I just see styled table but instead of values I see as plain text this ` {{ Form::checkbox('check',1,null,array('id'=>'checkb'))}}`. Not checkboxes but that tag as text.

Comment: what's the full name of that partial file?

Comment: oh, yeah, my file was not named as a blade. my bad ( thanks